# Spring batch get lastJobExecution

Tags: spring-batch

I need to process DB data from last job execution till now.

There is the JobRepository class. It has getLastJobExecution(jobName, jobParams) method. To get the last job execution, I should somehow extract last job parameters.

Is there a possibility provided by spring batch to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access [SB metadata tables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) with direct queries if interface exposed from `JobRepository` is not enough for your needs.